# How do I debug Javascript served through HtmlService?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-apps-script, client, vivaldi

I'm using HtmlService to serve a webpage with a form and some Javascript, but I don't know to go about debugging the client-side code. Because HtmlService uses iframe sandboxing I can't use the browser dev console, and I can't figure out how to write logs to Stackdriver; neither console.log nor Logger.log seems to do anything. Since the code relies on accessing server-side functions I can't just download the page and open it in the browser either. Is there a good way to do this?

For reference here's my (incomplete) code:
`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_self"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <style>small {
        color: grey;
      }
      body {
        background-color: aliceblue;
      }
      div.container {
        background-color: white;
      }
      input:invalid, select:invalid{
        border-color: red;
      }
      input:valid, select:valid{
        border-color: darkgreen;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container border rounded-lg mt-2 mb-2 pt-2 pb-2" style="max-width: 50rem;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h1 class="text-center">Bokning av Informationskväll</h1>
          <hr/>
          <form id="bookingForm">
            <div class="form-row">
              <label class="form-group col">E-postadress<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required/></label>
              <label class="form-group col">För- och efternamn<input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullName" required/></label>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <div class="form-row">
              <label class="form-group col">Välj tilfälle<select class="form-control col required" name="eventId" id="timeSlotSelect" required></select></label>
              <label class="form-group col">Antal personer <small>(inklusive dig själv)</small>
                <select class="form-control col required" name="numVisitors" id="visitorSelect" required>
                  <option value="1" selected>Bara mig själv</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
              </label>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <div class="form-row">
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="submitButton">Boka</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      const form = document.forms['bookingForm'];
      const submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
      let timeSlotSelect = document.getElementById('timeSlotSelect');
      const visitorSelect = document.getElementById('visitorSelect');
      const timeSlots = google.script.run.withFailureHandler(failurePopup).getAvailableTimeslots();

      function populateTimeSlots(){
        //let timeSlots = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successPopup).withFailureHandler(failurePopup).getAvailableTimeslots();
        console.log(timeSlots);
        alert(timeSlots.toString());
        let option = document.createElement("OPTION");
        timeSlotSelect.options.add(option);
        option.value = "";
        option.text = "Välj tillfälle...";
        for (let timeSlot of timeSlots){
          console.log(timeSlot);
          let option = document.createElement("OPTION");
          timeSlotSelect.options.add(option);
          option.value = timeSlot.eventId;
          option.text = timeSlot.eventTitle + " [" + timeSlot.bookedSlots + "/" + timeSlot.maxCapacity + "]";
          if (timeSlot.availableSlots < 1){
            option.disabled = true;
          }
          console.log(option);
        }
      }

      function checkNumSlots(){
        //let timeSlots = google.script.run.getAvailableTimeslots().withFailureHandler(failurePopup);

      }

      function successPopup(message){
        alert("Success!\n "+message.toString();
        console.log(message);
      }
      function failurePopup(error){
        alert("Uh oh!\n "+error.toString());
        console.log(error);
      }
      function submitBooking(){
        //alert("Försöker skicka in bokning...");
        let formFields = new FormData(form);
        let timeStamp = new Date();
        formFields.set("timeStamp", timeStamp);
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successPopup).withFailureHandler(failurePopup).bookTimeSlot(formFields);
        form.reset();
      }
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        submitBooking();
      });
      window.addEventListener('load', populateTimeSlots);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`Code.gs`

```html
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var scriptLock = LockService.getScriptLock();

function initialSetup() {
  const properties = {spreadsheetId: "1s0qVkY_zgISKfKckWJeg49fJVLxedF5eOVnCybbI1hw", dataSheetName: "bookingData", infoSheetName: "eventInfo"};
  scriptProp.setProperties(properties);
  const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(properties.spreadsheetId);
}

function doGet(){
  var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
  output.setTitle("Bokning av infokväll Hälsingegymnasiet");
  return output;
}

function getAvailableTimeslots(){
  Logger.log("Sidan frågar efter tillgängliga tillfällen...");
  scriptLock.waitLock(30000);
  try {
    let events = [];
    const id = scriptProp.getProperty('spreadsheetId');
    const infoSheetName = scriptProp.getProperty('infoSheetName');
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    const eventSheet = ss.getSheetByName(infoSheetName);
    //Logger.log(header);
    const lastRow = eventSheet.getLastRow();
    const lastColumn = eventSheet.getLastColumn();
    const header = eventSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues()[0];
    const data = eventSheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-1, lastColumn).getValues();
    for (var i=0; i < lastRow-1; i++){
      let event = {};
      for (var j=0; j < lastColumn-1; j++){
        event[header[j]] = data[i][j];
        //Logger.log(header[j]+" : "+range[i][j]);
      }
      //Logger.log(event);
      events.push(event);
    }
    //Logger.log(events);
    return events;
  }catch(e){
    Logger.log("Ett fel inträffade: "+e);
    return e;
  }
  finally {
    scriptLock.releaseLock()
  }
}

function bookTimeslot(formData){
  scriptLock.waitLock(30000);
  try{
    Logger.log("Inskickat formulär: "+formData);
    const id = scriptProp.getProperty('spreadsheetId');
    const dataSheetName = scriptProp.getProperty('dataSheetName');
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    const bookingSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dataSheetName);
    const lastColumn = bookingSheet.getLastColumn();
    const header = bookingSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues()[0];



  }catch(e){
    Logger.log("Ett fel inträffade: "+e);
    return e;
  }finally{
    scriptLock.releaseLock();
  }
}
```

EDIT: Figured it out; turned out to be an issue with my web browser (Vivaldi). Switched to Google Chrome instead, and now everything works fine. Kind of strange considering both browsers are Chromium-based, but oh well.

Comment: *Because HtmlService uses sandboxing I can't use the browser dev console* What?!

Comment: As far as I can tell, HtmlService serves the HTML content in an iframe and re-writes whatever JS it contains. This means that 1. the pages HTML is hidden from the element inspector and 2. HTML/JS errors/messages/logs aren't printed to the console. Well, that's what I think happens at least.

Comment: Have you... *tried* using the browser dev console?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Well, yes, otherwise I wouldn't have said so. Either way, turned to be an issue with my web browser (Vivaldi); switched to Chrome and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out; turns out my browser (Vivaldi) doesn't play nice with whatever method HtmlService presents content. I switched to Google Chrome and now I get output in the dev console.